# not able to acess image from div by div id

Tags: jquery, html, image

I am trying to add `divs` and `image` in one div which is added, but when I tried to do some jQuery on that img I am not able to do.

```
$("#images img").click(function(event) {
    alert(1);
    $path = $(this).attr("src");
    $("#display_image").attr("src", $path);
    $("#dialog").dialog("open");
    event.preventDefault();
});

function getImage() {
    var start_date = (startDate.datepicker('getDate') || minDate).getTime() / 1000;
    var end_date = (endDate.datepicker('getDate') || maxDate).getTime() / 1000;
    var pixintraSearchAPI = "<myrequest>";
    $.getJSON(pixintraSearchAPI).done(function(data) {
        $("#images").empty();
        $.each(data.results, function(i, result) {
            $("<div class='thumbnail'><div class='thumbnail-inner'><img src='<myimg>' /></div></div>").appendTo("#images");
            if (i === 3) {
                return false;
            }
        });
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Wrap your click event inside $(function(){/* click event code here */});. Following is the modified code.

```
$(function(){
    $("#images img").click(function(event) {
        alert(1);
        var path = $(this).attr("src");
        $("#display_image").attr("src", path);
        $("#dialog").dialog("open");
        event.preventDefault();
    });
});

function getImage() {
    var start_date = (startDate.datepicker('getDate') || minDate).getTime() / 1000;
    var end_date = (endDate.datepicker('getDate') || maxDate).getTime() / 1000;
    var pixintraSearchAPI = "<myrequest>";
    $.getJSON(pixintraSearchAPI).done(function(data) {
        $("#images").empty();
        $.each(data.results, function(i, result) {
            $("<div class='thumbnail'><div class='thumbnail-inner'><img src='<myimg>' /></div></div>").appendTo("#images");
            if (i === 3) {
                return false;
            }
        });
    });
}
```

Comment: Still the problem is same

Comment: Still I am facing same issue, my dialog is not opened

Comment: I cannot see any call to getImage() function. I assume that you are calling this function and it works. I just have change $path to var path in my answer. Please try again.